# Where do Booksellers on Amazon get new books that are published only on KDP and ingramSpark?

Tags: publishing

Where do Booksellers on Amazon obtain new books that are only printed on Amazon?
Are royalties forfeited when a book is sold by Amazon booksellers through amazon?
What ensures that the author gets due royalties on all new books sold?

Answer (score 1):

The booksellers on Amazon obtain the new books by print on demand from Amazon. They cannot keep the royalties. That would be illegal.

As far as trusting that the author would get their royalties, it is not a worry, but if you have published a book you could order a book from whomever you want to check out and see if the royalty comes to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few books published on amazon and they are only available on Amazon because I've only published them via KDP ([Kindle Desktop Publishing site](https://kdp.amazon.com)).

Amazon KDP now provides a way to create both Kindle and Print versions of your books.

Previously Amazon had a site named createspace.com (it is no longer functioning) which was used for Print Copy Publication.

Basically, it works like this:
Amazon handles the printing, delivering and payment (fulfillment) for you and they take a royalty from each book you publish.

You can publish your book as Kindle only or Print only or both.

If you add your book to the [KDP Select program](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G200798990) then you promise to not publish your book anywhere else digitally but then Amazon Prime and Unlimited customers can read your book for free but you get paid from a group fund.
Each month you will be paid according to how much is in the fund and how many pages of your book are read by readers.

I think the system works quite well for independent writers.  I make about $15 - $30 a month on sales from my books and it's rewarding to see your books on Amazon.

I currently have one two titles which are available as print and digital and I have a few other titles which are only digital.  I have one title that is enrolled into KDP Select.  It all works out pretty well.

So books you find only on Amazon are most likely published exclusively through the KDP program.